# MYSQL delete all results having count(*)=1

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-delete

I have a table taged with two fields sesskey (varchar32 , index) and products (int11), now I have to delete all rows that having group by sesskey count(*) = 1.
I'm trying a fews methods but all fails.

Example:

```
delete from taged where sesskey in (select sesskey from taged group by sesskey having count(*) = 1)
```

The sesskey field could not be a primary key because its repeated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DELETE  si
FROM    t_session si
JOIN    (
        SELECT  sesskey
        FROM    t_session so
        GROUP BY
                sesskey
        HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
        ) q
ON      q.sesskey = si.sesskey
```

You need to have a join here. Using a correlated subquery won't work.

See this article in my blog for more detail:

- [**Keeping rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/07/keeping-rows/)

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me in a recent mysql version. I had to use the example from your blog (LEFT JOIN, ID IS NULL). 
I managed to delete the wrong rows also :p (had to use IS NOT NULL for my case)

Comment: Does this work even if `t_session` is `TEMPORARY`? I was told including a table twice in a query is incompatible with use of `TEMPORARY TABLE` because of a [13-year-old "Can't reopen table" bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327).

Comment: @DamianYerrick: I don't know if it works in the recent versions, but it didn't in the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The SubQuery should work</s>

```
 Delete from taged 
  Where sesskey in 
     (Select sesskey 
      From taged 
      Group by sesskey 
      Having count(*) = 1)
```

EDIT:  Thanks to @Quassnoi comment below... The above will ***NOT*** work in MySql, as MySql restricts referencing the table being updated or deleted from, in a Subquery i you must do the same thing using a Join ...

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'taged' for update in FROM clause

Comment: That error is confusing... There's no "Update" going on here... What is it referring to ? The use of the tablename oin the Delet clause?  or the use of the tablename in the subquery (which is neither Updating nor deleting anything)

Comment: `MySQL` does not support target tables in the correlated subqueries (be it `DELETE` or `UPDATE`). Yes, the error is confusing.

Comment: @Quassnoi,  Thx,  I did not know this.. Do not use MySQL, but I will remember this... I bet (assume) this rule also applies to Updates which have subqueries in the Where clause - (I'm going to take a wild stab and guess that's what the error message was actually drafted for...) ?

Comment: `@Charles`: sure, that is what it was intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're using an older (pre 4.1) version of MySQL and don't have access to subqueries you need to select your data into a table, then join that table with the original:

```
CREATE TABLE delete_me_table (sesskey varchar32, cur_total int);

INSERT INTO delete_me_table SELECT sesskey, count(*) as cur_total FROM orig_table
WHERE cur_total = 1 GROUP BY sesskey;

DELETE FROM orig_table INNER JOIN delete_me_table USING (sesskey);
```

Now you have a table left over named `delete_me_table` which contains a history of all the rows you deleted.  You can use this for archiving, trending, other fun and unusual things to surprise yourself with.