# MySQL: DELETE rows beyond nth row within group

Tags: php, mysql

I insert rows into a table with time-stamps (`time`). I could have multiple rows that are identical except `id` and `time`. I want to delete all rows that are beyond 5 "iterations". I only want to keep 5 iterations of an instance's "history".

Instance = new entry for `name`

History = the entries for a particular `name`

**Example:**

```
id    name    value    time
1     blue    15       12/1/2016
2     blue    16       12/2/2016
3     blue    12       12/3/2016
4     blue    43       12/4/2016
5     blue    12       12/5/2016
6     blue    9        12/6/2016
7     blue    33       12/7/2016
8     red     15       12/5/2016
9     red     15       12/8/2016
```

**After Delete:**

```
id    name    value    time
3     blue    12       12/3/2016
4     blue    43       12/4/2016
5     blue    12       12/5/2016
6     blue    9        12/6/2016
7     blue    33       12/7/2016
8     red     15       12/5/2016
9     red     15       12/8/2016
```

Comment: Five rows based on just the `name` column?

Comment: Don't throw jargon at us. What's an "iteration"? What's an "instance"? What's a "history"? These terms are meaningless in the context of your tables, and you didn't bother to explain them.

Comment: Easy, @shmosel. I was trying to explain it with words as well. If I was throwing jargon, I wouldn't use quotation marks. I'm assuming you know the basic meaning of the words "iteration" and "history".

Comment: Also, five rows based on what? time? decreasing id?

Comment: @tom On the contrary, quotations means you're using jargon and you know it. Of course I know the basic meaning, but it's unclear what they mean in this context without making assumptions about the nature of your data.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh For this example, yes, on name. Based one time, yes. So sorted in descending order by time, keep top 5, per say.

Comment: DELETE with HAVING and COUNT() if more than 5 with a WHERE clause ought to do it.

Comment: @tom I did not mean that in a belligerent way, and I'm sorry if you took it that way. I was just pointing out that the use of quotations indicates that you realize (at some level) you're using the words outside of their natural meaning.

Comment: @shmosel I tried updating my question to explain further. Your duplicate suggestion might be the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: so what do you want to, delete or select and just group by with a limit? you say the duplicate might be the solution; what do you want to do here exactly? there's no delete in that link.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe I can modify the solution in the duplicate to delete instead of select. I want to delete rows from the table. I think I explained it fine in the question.

Comment: *"UPDATE: Are we sure this is a duplicate? I'm not selecting, I'm deleting. I think having an answer here would be beneficial."* - So in your saying to shmosel earlier *"Your duplicate suggestion might be the solution."* - the person who closed it based themselves on that. You should have read through that first before telling them that. As I mentioned earlier *"DELETE with HAVING and COUNT() if more than 5 with a WHERE clause ought to do it."* is one way to do this.

Comment: Yes, it's duplicate absolutely. Instead of `select` you can use the same answer for `delete` as well with little modification may be. So consider yourself putting some effort. If it's not duplicate then it would have been reopened by someone already commented earlier like @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Rahul I'm not going to reopen in case you may be wondering. If the OP disagrees, then they'll have to ask you to reopen it. I won't go against anyone's judgement. I gave them a pseudo method but they didn't respond to it when I posted. However, there is no DELETE syntax in that dupe.

Comment: @Rahul it's hard to respond to everyone. comments are getting too long here. Let me look into your solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, sure Fred. in comment, I just meant to OP that you have the privilege to reopen single handedly. So in case my decision to close it is wrong then you can counterfeit it.

Comment: @Rahul *"that you have the privilege to reopen single handedly"* as do you ;-) so.... if you feel (and the OP) that the question should be reopened, then I guess it probably should.

Comment: Well, reopened it but there is not much difference between the marked dupe though.

Comment: [DELETE FROM HAVING COUNT(\*) in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10554627/) --- 
[MYSQL delete all results having count(\*)=1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1902014/) --- 
[MySQL DELETE With a Sub-Query using Having and Count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4936838/) - Just to name a few; this after Googling (basically what I said originally) "delete with having and count mysql". One of those stand to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't want to delete an entire group that has more than 5 rows as a group. I only want to delete the excess beyond 5 rows.

Comment: they were examples and good ones at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the adopted solution from the suggested almost-duplicate question:

```
delete l.* from table_name L inner join (
    select name, group_concat(id order by time desc) grouped_value from table_name 
) R on l.name=r.name and find_in_set(id,grouped_value) > 5
```